# How to rotate a selected number of vertexes using the end vertex as the pivot point?

Tags: vertices

I been  using blender 2.8 and I can't figure out how to rotate a selected number of vertexes around another vertex at the end of the selection. When I highlight the vertexes and then click on the end vertex, the rotation tool is placed in the correct position, but the vertexes are deselected. How do I keep the vertexes selected while placing the rotation tool?

Comment: If using Active Element, as shown by @thibsert, Shift-select the pivot vertex twice to make it active.

Answer (score 2):

Change the **Pivot Point** to **Active Element** :
[image: Pivot point : Active Element]

The last selected vertex/edge/face (which appears white) is now the pivot point of the transformations.

Comment: Thanks for the info as this seems to be the fastest solution for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to select the vertex you want to rotate other vertices around; Use **Cursor to Selected**; Make the cursor your pivot; select the vertices and rotate. In this method the order of selection is not important.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I finally figured this out but, thibert's solution was what I was looking for.